# Difference between session and params in Controller class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking at a rails example for shopping carts and in the ApplicationController class I see code like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  private

    def current_cart 
      Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = cart.id
      cart
    end
end
```

so it is using a **Cart.find(session[:cart_id])**

Then I go to carts_controller.rb  and CartController class and I see code like this:

```
 def update
    @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
```

so here it is using **Cart.find(params[:id])**

But I can't understand why we used session to pass params in the AppController but we used normal params in the CartController and could we use swithc use of them ? or is it how rails works and always session goes to AppController?   Would be greta if someone can explain this in more details

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`params` live in the url or in the post body of a form, so it vanishes as soon as the query is made.

Session persists between multiple requests (the info are often stored in cookies but this depends on your configuration).

To be short:

- params: one request only (creation of one object, access to one particular page)
- session: info to be persisted (cart, logged user..)

Comment: Thanks, make more sense now.  One more question: so still it is correct if for some need I use "session" in the CartsController class instead of using it in ApplicationControlelr class?  or sessions must always be in that class?