# Is form data passed through session or params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-variables

I am not understanding the difference between `session` and `params` in the following application.

> A user submits a new movie form. How would the associated controller access the title of the movie?
>
> 1. `session['title']`
> 2. `session.title`
> 3. `params['title']`
> 4. `params.title`
> 5. All of the above

Based on the StackOverflow answer at [Difference between session and params in Controller class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442037/difference-between-session-and-params-in-controller-class):

> `params` live in the url or in the post body of a form, so it vanishes as soon as the query is made.
>
> Session persists between multiple requests (the info are often stored in cookies but this depends on your configuration).
>
> To be short:
>
> - params: one request only (creation of one object, access to one particular page)
> - session: info to be persisted (cart, logged user..)

I chose **(1) `session ['title']`** on the quiz and got the answer wrong. I chose (1) because I thought it involved accessing information that had to persist.

Am I misinterpreting the question and maybe this falls more under "one request only" so the answer should be **(3) `params['title']`**?

Comment: I was not given any other information on the quiz. Is it possible to do the question without having other information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To attempt to answer your question in the context of this quiz instead of just in the context of code, consider where it says that:

> params live in the url or in the post body of a form, so it vanishes
>   as soon as the query is made.

Now consider that the question itself says:

> A user submits a new movie **form**. How would the associated controller
>   access the title of the movie?

So the question is saying that the user interacts by filling out a form which is then `post`ed to the server. This is exactly the **"post body of a form"** mentioned in your notes.

So the correct answer is **3) `params['title']`**.

Now, once this data is accessed, it CAN BE PLACED into the session, but that's for the developer to do or decide, and that's not really within the scope of what's being talked about here.

You also know that, in the context of this question, the session is not what's used because your question only refers to a single request: the sending of the form. If your question referred to data sent from the form that had to persist over a few more requests (such as a multi-page form), then the session might come into play.

Answer (score 0):

Before access data you need to put it. In default rails generated forms all data is send in one request in params. If you have form that points to User#create action and have 'name' input, you will have params['name'] in User#create action.

Session is another thing. It's hard to find sessions in standart generated rails scaffold. You can access session as a hash. session['name'] will store name between requests. [Read more](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions)

So, params are are generated for one request - to transfer data from user to server, sessions are used not for transfer data, but for store it.